# Can't access RDS Environment variables in EC2 instance using Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am currently unable to access my RDS environment variables in the EC2 instance. They are both linked using Elastic Beanstalk.

I am trying to use the RDS environment variables in a PHP script using the `$_SERVER` global variable but every time I check on the console these are always empty strings. Also if I run `echo ${RDS_HOSTNAME}` on the console I also get an empty string.

However when I run `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment` I get the following with the correct credentials.

```json
{
    "COMPOSER_HOME":"/root",
    "RDS_DB_NAME":"dbname",
    "RDS_HOSTNAME":"dbhost.rds.amazonaws.com",
    "RDS_PASSWORD":"dbpassword",
    "RDS_PORT":"3306",
    "RDS_USERNAME":"dbusername"
}
```

I've also connected to the database via the `mysql` command just to make sure that the EC2 instance can access the RDS database and it worked.
Using `mysql -u dbusername -h dbhost.rds.amazonaws.com -p`

Comment: EBS stands for Elastic Block Store, not Elastic Beanstalk. I don't think those environment variables are set by default in SSH sessions on the EC2 instance, they are only set for the PHP server process.

Comment: When trying to use them in a PHP script I get the following `PDOException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known'` However if I manually type in RDS logins then the same script works.

Comment: If you're running the script manually from the console, then the same thing I said above applies. I would only expect those environment variables to be set automatically for the Apache HTTPD server instance that your main PHP website runs in. see: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-pass-variables/ "Environment properties aren't automatically exported to the shell, even though they are present in the instance. Instead, environment properties are made available to the application through the stack that it runs in, based on which platform you're using."

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Is there a way to automatically populate the RDS environment variables inside of the EC2 CLI? For example I want to run a script on the server that requires these to run some database migration, these fields are also required for a CRON job that will need to be run.

I've tried assigning them to in my `.ebextension` file using `export RDS_HOSTNAME=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k RDS_HOSTNAME)` but the command line variables are still empty.

Comment: `.ebextension` isn't used when you login via SSH. You would need to add that `export` statement somewhere like the `.bash_profile` script. Or just run it manually as the first thing you do after you login.

Comment: Aren't these going to just get overwritten every time you boot a new instance?

Comment: Yes, Elastic Beanstalk isn't meant for you to run manual scripts on. Ideally you would never login to Elastic Beanstalk servers at all.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the need to sign onto the server to touch anything. 

I ideally want to set up a way to assign the Environment Variables to the command line so my migration scripts can run to adjust the RDS database and then create a CRON job to call a PHP script that will require access to these Environment Variables so I can process information in the RDS environment.

Comment: You're cron job schedule is also going to get overwritten. You should be looking at DB migration processes that run as part of your application's deployment. And you should be looking at other ways to schedule jobs on AWS than a cron job on a beanstalk server.

Answer (score 0):

> The command is failing because it is not getting the environment variables set in the Beanstalk Environment.

On **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2), the EB env variables are stored in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env`. Thus when you ssh to your EB instance,  you can use the following to populate your env variables (need to sudo to root firs):

```
sudo su 
export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
echo $RDS_HOSTNAME
```

This is **undocumented** way of doing this on AL2.

Note:

The env variables shouldn't have **spaces**. Also the file is **not immediately available**. It gets created when deployment succeeds.